# AppBarLayout view becomes blank when FAB(FloatingActionButton) is clicked in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-support-design

**This problem occurs on Android version 4.2.1 and the layour works fine on 5.0.2**

I am using the new Co-ordinator layout with AppBarLayout and FloatingActionButton and recycler view

Whenever i scrollup the recyclerview the toolbar hides which is working perfectly fine  but when the toolbar is hidden and i click on the FAB button and then scroll down the toolbar view is not visible  and again a click on fab button brings the toolbar back.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: is it resolved ? am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `FrameLayout` declaration before the `AppBarLayout`. I'm not sure if this will help you but as far as I know the views that have `layout_behavior` attribute should be declared before the `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

add this `invisible` view as the following , i works for me .

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
 <View
            android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```